# comparing two uuid in sqlalchemy core

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy 1.2

In short what produces errors is this :

```
uuidvar = uuid4()
mytable.select().where(mytable.c.uuidColumn == uuidvar) #where mytable is of type sqlalchemy.Table
```

Error :

```
  File "/Users/remi/PycharmProjects/my_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 448, in process
    value = _python_UUID(value)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/uuid.py", line 137, in __init__
    hex = hex.replace('urn:', '').replace('uuid:', '')

sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.AttributeError) 'UUID' object has no attribute 'replace' [SQL: 'SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM myTable \nWHERE uuidColumn = '%(uuidColumn_1)s']
```

With a table like this :

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
  uuidColumn uuid primary key default uuid_generate_v4()
  col1 text,
  col2 text,
  col3 text
)
```

and table generate in python :

```
metadata = MetaData(engine=db) # db is created by "create_engine", nothing fancy
myTable = Table('myTable', metadata, autoload=True)
```

Comment: could you share the reflected metadata for `myTable`

Comment: what do you mean by that ?

Comment: i want to know what sqlalchemy type `myTable.c.uuidColumn` has.

Comment: Based on the error message you are getting, I bet that if you change: `uuidvar = uuid4()` to `uuidvar = uuid4().hex` your code will work.

Comment: yup, the suggestion provided by @JoshKupershmidt will work.

Comment: Ok. So as far as I can see, these are juste work around, there is not way to support uuid in sqlalchemy (by default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. To solve this error, you need to define uuidColumn with as_uuid=True. Like so:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
uuidColumn = db.Column(postgresql.UUID(as_uuid=True))
```

For more details see Michael Bayer's comments here: https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3323/in-099-uuid-columns-are-broken-with

Comment: Should relationships also use this?